# Nhibernate Search on different domains

Tags: nhibernate, lucene.net, nhibernate.search

I have two websites which are required to access the same Lucene index using nHibernate search. Problem is they are of course on different domains so I think they are breaking the session.

As soon as the second website fires up the first website suddenly gets time out problems when trying to update an entity (there are listeners on the entities).

The only way I can think of getting this to work is to store an instance of the session in a webservice. Is this the right way of doing it? If so how do I even pass a session object to and fro from a webservice??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't an issue, it was rather an exception which was being thrown during the indexing process which caused a slow down.